# I'm looking for CRC-16/ARC Delphi(Pascal) Function

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, pascal, crc, crc16

I'm looking for a CRC-16/ARC function in Delphi(Pascal).

Bytes :

```
5a 02 20 70 11 15 20 26 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00
```

CRC value:

```
0x79B9
```

[image]

Here is some C++ source code:

```cpp
unsigned short const crc16_table[256] = {
        0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
        0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
        0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
        0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
        0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
        0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
        0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
        0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
        0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
        0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
        0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
        0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
        0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
        0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
        0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
        0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,
        0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
        0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
        0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
        0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
        0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
        0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
        0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
        0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,
        0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
        0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
        0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
        0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
        0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
        0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
        0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
        0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040
};
//============================================================================
unsigned short crc16(unsigned short crc, unsigned char const *buffer, unsigned int len)
{
        while (len--)
                crc = (unsigned short)((crc >> 8)^(crc16_table[(crc^(*buffer++))&0xff]));
        return crc;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code writing service, and we're also not a link locator. Please spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with this site and how it works. Good luck. (And Google is an excellent source for locating links to things, and it's sole job is to find them and display them to you. You should learn to use it.)

Answer (score 3):

The Delphi translation of the C++ code you provided would look like this:

```pascal
const 
  crc16_table: array[0..255] of Word = (
    $0000, $C0C1, $C181, $0140, $C301, $03C0, $0280, $C241,
    $C601, $06C0, $0780, $C741, $0500, $C5C1, $C481, $0440,
    $CC01, $0CC0, $0D80, $CD41, $0F00, $CFC1, $CE81, $0E40,
    $0A00, $CAC1, $CB81, $0B40, $C901, $09C0, $0880, $C841,
    $D801, $18C0, $1980, $D941, $1B00, $DBC1, $DA81, $1A40,
    $1E00, $DEC1, $DF81, $1F40, $DD01, $1DC0, $1C80, $DC41,
    $1400, $D4C1, $D581, $1540, $D701, $17C0, $1680, $D641,
    $D201, $12C0, $1380, $D341, $1100, $D1C1, $D081, $1040,
    $F001, $30C0, $3180, $F141, $3300, $F3C1, $F281, $3240,
    $3600, $F6C1, $F781, $3740, $F501, $35C0, $3480, $F441,
    $3C00, $FCC1, $FD81, $3D40, $FF01, $3FC0, $3E80, $FE41,
    $FA01, $3AC0, $3B80, $FB41, $3900, $F9C1, $F881, $3840,
    $2800, $E8C1, $E981, $2940, $EB01, $2BC0, $2A80, $EA41,
    $EE01, $2EC0, $2F80, $EF41, $2D00, $EDC1, $EC81, $2C40,
    $E401, $24C0, $2580, $E541, $2700, $E7C1, $E681, $2640,
    $2200, $E2C1, $E381, $2340, $E101, $21C0, $2080, $E041,
    $A001, $60C0, $6180, $A141, $6300, $A3C1, $A281, $6240,
    $6600, $A6C1, $A781, $6740, $A501, $65C0, $6480, $A441,
    $6C00, $ACC1, $AD81, $6D40, $AF01, $6FC0, $6E80, $AE41,
    $AA01, $6AC0, $6B80, $AB41, $6900, $A9C1, $A881, $6840,
    $7800, $B8C1, $B981, $7940, $BB01, $7BC0, $7A80, $BA41,
    $BE01, $7EC0, $7F80, $BF41, $7D00, $BDC1, $BC81, $7C40,
    $B401, $74C0, $7580, $B541, $7700, $B7C1, $B681, $7640,
    $7200, $B2C1, $B381, $7340, $B101, $71C0, $7080, $B041,
    $5000, $90C1, $9181, $5140, $9301, $53C0, $5280, $9241,
    $9601, $56C0, $5780, $9741, $5500, $95C1, $9481, $5440,
    $9C01, $5CC0, $5D80, $9D41, $5F00, $9FC1, $9E81, $5E40,
    $5A00, $9AC1, $9B81, $5B40, $9901, $59C0, $5880, $9841,
    $8801, $48C0, $4980, $8941, $4B00, $8BC1, $8A81, $4A40,
    $4E00, $8EC1, $8F81, $4F40, $8D01, $4DC0, $4C80, $8C41,
    $4400, $84C1, $8581, $4540, $8701, $47C0, $4680, $8641,
    $8201, $42C0, $4380, $8341, $4100, $81C1, $8081, $4040
  );

function crc16(crc: Word; buffer: PByte; len: LongWord): Word;
begin
  while (len <> 0) do
  begin
    crc := Word((crc shr 8) xor crc16_table[(crc xor buffer^) and $FF]);
    Inc(buffer);
    Dec(len);
  end;
  Result := crc;
end;
```

For example:

```pascal
const
  bytes: array[0..105] of Byte = (
    $5a, $02, $20, $70, $11, $15, $20, $26, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
    $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00, $00,
    $00, $00
  );
var
  crc: Word;
begin
  crc := crc16(0, @bytes[0], Length(bytes));
  // crc is $79B9 
end;
```